Convert a RGB LiDAR raster image to a greyscale height map in QGIS
I am fairly new to the world of GIS and also using QGIS. I normally use a greyscale height map to create a 3D terrain in external 3D software. I have a location where I only have access to a RGB raster LiDAR map, and I wondered if there's a way to convert it to a greyscale height map that I can use to displace my surface in my 3D software.
See attached images of the raster I have and the sort of greyscale image I would like to achieve.
** Update **
I found a better source for the LiDAR info I needed, so this is now not an issue for me.



Sorry, not happening. This is an image of elevations dropped on top of a shaded relief. This does not look like heights but, rather a ground filtered point cloud turned into a DEM, not DSM or heights. Heights are whats left after the ground is normalized out and a DSM is everything (non-filtered elevations). Whereas, a DEM is the ground elevations only (with above ground measurements filtered out). That aside, this image is for visualization only, not analysis. In other words, it a picture not data. Follow recommendations of requesting the derived lidar data products, not raw point cloud.

Hi, thanks for your input. Trying now to track down DTM (which was what this one was labelled as)

A DTM is a digital terrain model, which aims to be a model of the ground surface, and a DSM is a digital surface model, which shows things like the tops of trees and buildings. If this is UK Environment Agency data then the derived surfaces should be available...

Thanks - I normally use DEFRA LiDAR but this location is Wales and I'm just figuring out how to access that data as it's a different platform - there's not as much coverage as England but I have now found enough at (2m accuracy) to cover my site - in the elevation greyscale I was looking for.

I'd class this as very hard to do. It's been coloured by height (there's a brown blob at the top, a different green in the valley) and then shaded by a hill-shading algorithm which considers an artificial light source which appears to be coming from the NW. Deconvoluting these two processes is tricky and can't be done "locally" since a dark pixel has no colour information yet could be a shaded pixel at the top of a mountain or the bottom of a valley.
A possible approach might be to feed a learning algorithm with a bunch of known DEMs  and the resulting hillshade, such that it learns how to create a DEM from a hillshade... But this might require a lot of training and be very error-prone anyway. I doubt its been done already (but I'll search in a bit and update) and it might be easier to get the source data.

OK, thanks for your input
